# The easy part of Solovay's theorem about stationary

Tags: set-theory

In Jech, *Set Theory*, the proof of the Solovay's theorem about the disjoint union of a stationary set (in $k$ regular), into $k$ many disjoint stationary subsets, starts showing that this decomposition is possible for the stationary subsets of $E_\omega^k=\{\alpha\in k: \text{cof}(\alpha)=\omega\}$ (pag. 94, Lemma 8.8).

This is the proof.

[image]

I can't understand why the $\gamma_\eta$ are $k$. Surely the regularity of $k$ implies that if the $\gamma_\eta$ had sup $k$, their cardinality would be $k$, but why can't they be definitely equal to or bounded by something lower than $k$?

Comment: Where do you read that $\gamma_\eta=\kappa$?

Comment: I edited last question. @Asaf Karagila I meant $|\{\gamma_\eta: \eta\in k\}|$ is $k$.

Answer (score 3):

The regularity of $\kappa$ does not imply that $\sup\gamma_\eta$ is $\kappa$. Rather it implies that ***any*** unbounded set must have cardinality $\kappa$.

If you agree that $\sup\gamma_\eta=\kappa$, which follows from the fact that $\gamma_\eta\geq\eta$, then you have to agree—by regularity of $\kappa$—that there are at least $\kappa$ of them.

Comment: if $\gamma_\eta > \eta$, i agree with you ($\gamma_{\gamma_\eta}> \gamma_\eta$ and so on). But can't be the case $\gamma_\eta=\eta$? I can't see why $sup \gamma_\eta=k$.

Comment: Sure, let it be $\eta$. But that means that for every $\eta<\kappa$, $\gamma_\eta=\eta$. So $\{\gamma_\eta\mid\eta<\kappa\}$ is actually a tail segment of $\kappa$...

Comment: Ok maybe i have it. If $\{\gamma_\eta : \eta<\kappa\}$ was bounded by $\delta<\kappa$, then $\gamma_\eta=\delta$ for every $\eta\geq\delta$. But $\gamma_{\delta+1}\geq\delta+1>\delta$. 

The case $\gamma_\eta=\eta$ for every $\eta$, it's ok, but in last post i meant what if $\gamma_\eta=\delta$ definetely, that's what i have just solved, right?

Comment: No, if the set is bounded by $\delta$ then $\gamma_\eta$ is undefined for any $\eta>\delta$.

Comment: The $\gamma_\eta$ are defined from Fodor's Lemma for each $\eta<\kappa$. I'm only showing that they are unbounded, i.e. the image of the function $\eta\to\gamma_\eta$ is cofinal in $\kappa$. I think we can prove this in the way i posted.

Comment: Jech writes as clearly as daylight, "we can find $\gamma_\eta\geq\eta$ ...". That's it. We're done proving that the $\gamma_\eta$'s are unbounded.